# Seeding: how to link a created entity to another?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I use [typeorm-seeding](https://github.com/w3tecch/typeorm-seeding) to seed my database handled by typeorm. I have 2 factories for 2 entities `Customer` and `Event`:

**Entitites**

```
// entity/Customer.ts
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToOne, ManyToMany, JoinTable, JoinColumn } from 'typeorm'
import { Event } from './Event'

@Entity()
export class Customer {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstname: string;

  @Column()
  lastname: string;

  @Column()
  email: string

  @ManyToMany(() => Event, event => event.customers, { cascade: true })
  @JoinTable()
  events: Promise<Event[]>
}


// entity/Event.ts
import { Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column, CreateDateColumn, OneToMany, ManyToMany, JoinTable, DeleteDateColumn } from 'typeorm'
import { Course } from './Course'
import { Customer } from './Customer'

@Entity()
export class Event {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Customer, customer => customer.events)
  @JoinTable()
  customers: Promise<Customer[]>
}
```

**Factories**

```
// factory/event.ts
import { define, factory } from 'typeorm-seeding'

import { Event } from '../../entity/Event'

define(Event, (faker) => {
  const event = new Event()

  event.id = faker.company.bsBuzz()
  event.name = faker.company.catchPhraseNoun()
  event.date = faker.date.recent()

  return event
})


// factory/customer.ts
import { Customer } from '../../entity/Customer'

define(Customer, (faker) => {
  const customer = new Customer()

  customer.firstname = faker.name.firstName()
  customer.lastname = faker.name.lastName()
  customer.email = faker.internet.email()

  return customer
})
```

As you can see a `Customer` can have multiple `Event`s and different `Customer`s can participate to the same `Event`. So my goal for the seeding part is to create 10 different `Event`s and then create 100 `Customer`s that participate at some of these `Event`s. So I created 2 seeding files:

```
// seed/create-events.ts
import { Factory, Seeder } from 'typeorm-seeding'
import { Event } from '../entity/Event'

export default class CreateEvents implements Seeder {
  public async run(factory: Factory): Promise<any> {
    await factory(Event)().createMany(10)
  }
}


// seed/create-customers.ts
import { Factory, Seeder } from 'typeorm-seeding'
import { Customer } from '../entity/Customer'

export default class CreateCustomers implements Seeder {
  // eslint-disable-next-line class-methods-use-this
  public async run(factory: Factory): Promise<any> {
    await factory(Customer)().createMany(100)
  }
}
```

However that only create some entries but doesn't link them together.

I know that I could use the `Event`'s factory inside of the the `Customer`'s one:

```
// factory/customer.ts
import { Customer } from '../../entity/Customer'

define(Customer, (faker) => {
  const customer = new Customer()

  customer.firstname = faker.name.firstName()
  customer.lastname = faker.name.lastName()
  customer.email = faker.internet.email()

  customer.events = factory(Event)().createMany(10)

  return customer
})
```

But that will just create 10 different `Event`s for each `Customer`.

So how to seed my `Customer`s in a way that they are linked to some `Event`s created during the `seed:run` command?